JavaFX MouseDragged into TouchMoved
I need to simulate finger movement on a touch screen when dragging a mouse.
I try to use setOnMouseDragged and create my TouchEvent.
(Note that tablehistory is a TableView)
tablehistory.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            TouchPoint touchPoint = new TouchPoint(
                    2,
                    TouchPoint.State.MOVED,
                    event.getX(),
                    event.getY(),
                    event.getScreenX(),
                    event.getScreenY(),
                    event.getTarget(),
                    new PickResult(event.getTarget(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY())
            );

            java.util.List<javafx.scene.input.TouchPoint> touchPoints = new ArrayList<>();
            touchPoints.add(touchPoint);

            TouchEvent touchEvent = new TouchEvent(
                        event.getSource(),
                        event.getTarget(),
                        TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVED,
                        touchPoint,
                        touchPoints,
                        2,
                        false,
                        false,
                        false,
                        false
            );

            Event.fireEvent(event.getTarget(), touchEvent);
        });

My TouchEvent is visible in debug:
touch event: TOUCH_MOVED point:TouchPoint [state = MOVED, id = 2, target = StackPane@15a8702b[styleClass=placeholder], x = 912.0, y = 298.0, z = 0.0, pickResult = PickResult [node = StackPane@15a8702b[styleClass=placeholder], point = Point3D [x = 911.0, y = 257.0, z = 0.0], distance = 1.0]

But it differs in the distance field from TouchEvent caused by a real touch on the screen.
Real TouchEvent:
touch event: TOUCH_MOVED point:TouchPoint [state = MOVED, id = 1, target = StackPane@15a8702b[styleClass=placeholder], x = 778.0, y = 375.0, z = 0.0, pickResult = PickResult [node = StackPane@15a8702b[styleClass=placeholder], point = Point3D [x = 777.0, y = 334.0, z = 0.0], distance = 1360.3325193588557]

And accordingly my TouchEvent does not work as I need (in this specific example it is table scrolling).
I use java corretto 1.8
Basically I'm looking for any way to make the table scroll smoothly without using the mouse wheel or scrollbar.
Everything works fine on Windows with touchscreen, even without this code. But I need the ability to scroll the table with the mouse anywhere in the table, and not just by the scrollbar or using the wheel.
The problems start on Linux, where there is no normal support for touch screens. There, moving a finger across the screen simply repeats the behavior of a mouse with the left button pressed, so it was decided to programmatically catch such events and somehow call TouchEvent ourselves.
So far the following solution has been found, but it looks a lot like a kludge:
AtomicReference<Double> dragEventY = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
tablehistory.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
    dragEventY.set(event.getY());
    ...
}

tablehistory.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
    ScrollBar tableHistoryScrollBar = (ScrollBar) tablehistory.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
    if (tableHistoryScrollBar != null) {
        System.out.println("Scroll = " + tableHistoryScrollBar.getValue());
        if (event.getY() < dragEventY.get()) {
            tableHistoryScrollBar.increment();
            dragEventY.set(event.getY());
        } else if (event.getY() > dragEventY.get()) {
            tableHistoryScrollBar.decrement();
            dragEventY.set(event.getY());
        }
    }
});



do you run that code on the same device (the same touch screen)?

@MartinFrank yes and I also tried to do this on Linux and Windows

do you start your dragging simulation with a mouse_down event?

@MartinFrank everything works fine in windows with touchscreen, even without this code. But I need the ability to scroll the table with the mouse anywhere in the table, and not just by the scrollbar or using the wheel.

that is a great hint :-D i will take some time to dig deeper - thatnks for clearing that out (maybe you could add this information to your questions, so others don't have to ask again

”I use java corretto 1.8” -> that is really old,  I recommend something modern like java/javafx 22.

There are some undocumented settings that might help you simulate touch functionality.

@jewelsea Unfortunately, the methods you suggested did not help. Also, using new versions of Java is currently impossible due to a number of requirements.
